# How to create custom style Linked (paragraph and character) in MS Word using OpenXml.Wordprocessing and C#

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml

How to create custom style Linked (paragraph and character) in MS Word using OpenXml.Wordprocessing and C#:

I would like to change this piece of code to create a linked style insted of character style:

```
StyleDefinitionsPart part = document.MainDocumentPart.StyleDefinitionsPart;

Styles styles = part.Styles;
Style style = new Style()
{
    StyleId = "somestyle",
    CustomStyle = true
};
style.Append(new StyleName() { Val = "somestyle" });
style.Append(new BasedOn() { Val = "Normal" });
style.Append(new NextParagraphStyle() { Val = "Normal" });
style.Append(new UIPriority() { Val = 900 });

StyleRunProperties styleRunProperties = new StyleRunProperties();
Color color1 = new Color() { Val = "somecolor" };
FontSize fontSize1 = new FontSize();
fontSize1.Val = new StringValue(customStyle.FontSize);

styleRunProperties.Append(color1);
styleRunProperties.Append(fontSize1);
style.Append(styleRunProperties);
styles.Append(style);
```

Any idea?

Comment: Create a Word document with a linked style. Look at the code the Open XML SDK Productivity Tool uses to generate the style. But it appears to be an ATTRIBUTE named Type of the Style element, not a child element, so something like `style.Append(new StyleType() { Val = "link" });` see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.style(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: Thanks a lot for your the Open XML SDK Productivity Tool recommendation. It was really helpful. The solution is to create two styles - one for paragraph and one for character and linked them by LinkedStyle attribute

Comment: You should post this as an Answer :-) - which is allowed by Stack Overflow - and mark it as such. Good research and good question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Open XML SDK Productivity Tool recommendation  was really helpful. The solution is to create two styles - one for paragraph and one for character and linked them by LinkedStyle attribute.